# NuGet error. "Package restore failedd.Rolling back changes for ...", no matter what package I try to install

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017, vs-community-edition

I have a problem with my NuGet, I tried everything, but it simply wouldn't work.

Whenever I create a new project, it wouldn't work, I can't install, update, delete, anything. I leave here the Nuget.config file, maybe I can get some help...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <activePackageSource>
   <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"     protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="telerik.com" value="https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you mean you will get this error when you try to install any package to a new blank project or just for asp.net web project? Or you can try to create a blank c# class library project and install some packages to check. If you still get this error, you can share us some more detail info, such as, screenshot for the error log in the output window, detail reproduce steps.

Comment: I can install nuget packages when creating a console app, allso when i create an asp.net framework mvc app. When I create a new Core App it fails, and also with the old ones I have. But this is strange, because I managed to install packages until yesterday

Comment: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1).

Comment: From the Output window

Comment: Now the interesting problem is that I have Core apps, with both core 1.0 and core 1.1 and I could install packages with NuGet, but now I can't install anything, like anything at all, not even updating the ones that I have

Comment: I'm confused about what you said "I could install packages with NuGet, but now I can't install anything". You can install package but can NOT install anything, what is anything, such as? You should give the detail steps to reproduce this issue and give what have you do and the screenshot about the result.

Comment: I am working on some projects for about three weeks and at the beginning I was able to install packages(entity for example, and even nodeServices), but now I can't install packages anymore, not a single package. For as far as my English goes, there is a difference between different tenses (like past and present). So, I was able to install packages two weeks ago but now I can`t. It is just as simple as that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NuGet error. “Package restore failedd.Rolling back changes for …”, no matter what package I try to install

If I understand you correct, now you can not install the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices` to your project any more. Am I right?

If yes, you should to notice that the author of package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices` has released a new version **2.0** on **August 12, 2017 (8/12/2017) (several days ago)**, which supports: **netstandard2.0**

According to the .NET platform support, .NET Core has version 1.0 and version 2.0 and the version 1.0 corresponding .NET Standard 1.0 to 1.6, **the version 2.0 corresponding .NET Standard 2.0**. So install the .netstandard 2.0 package to the .net core 1.1, you will get the error "*Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1*"

To resolve this issue, you can install that package with the version **1.1.1** or update .net core to 2.0:

[image]

I installed that package with version 1.1.1 to the .net core 1.1, it works fine.

Hope this can help you.